# Search in Google Maps by everything not just street name

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I implemented autoCompleteSupportFragment to let user type and search in map but the result only appear to be street name i want to search by:
Co-ordinates
Geo Tag IDs
Area
Popular places/buildings

how to implement this?

```
autocompleteFragment =
            childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment)
                    as AutocompleteSupportFragment

        // Specify the types of place data to return.
        autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(listOf(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG))

        // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
            override fun onError(p0: Status) {
                //empty code block
            }

            override fun onPlaceSelected(p0: Place) {
                p0.latLng?.apply {
                    mapViewModel.googleMap.moveCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            LatLng(latitude, longitude), Coordinates.ZOOM
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [entire list](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/Place.Field) of available fields. You can probably check the [PlaceAutocompleteActivity](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos/blob/6e5cb15aff1e909e7917029cfb8cb911322d21ce/snippets/app/src/main/java/com/google/places/kotlin/PlaceAutocompleteActivity.kt) sample from the [android-places-demos](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-places-demos/) repo, and see which Place Field item suits you better.